# Power BI - Copying data to new column before refreshing data

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

This is what I hope to be a very simple issue, I'm just having a hard time putting the right search terms together in order to  find the answer.

Basically, I want to preserve the data from the last refresh before the data is refreshed again, in order to compare the difference.

Example:

I have a basic web scrape that runs off and grabs the latest stock price for Microsoft:

[image: Basic scrape to grab Microsoft stock price]

What I want to be able to do during the refresh is to first copy the current value (283.85) to a new column and *then* refresh the data, so that I have a side by side current and previous price.

Really tried to find an answer, but I don't think I'm using the correct terminology.

Comment: Power BI is not a database. When a dataset is refreshed, the previous content is lost.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this method. Would it be easier to add a date column to your current table and make it your record table? That way you can do a comparison and visuals from your data.

If you really want separate tables you could update your table with the date column and then write a table query to get your latest stock price according to date